# Hibernate Multitenant problema com identificação do tenancy atual

Tags: java, hibernate, multi-tenancy

Estou usando o multitenant do hibernate por schemas, uso o banco de dados Postgresql.

Meu problema é o seguinte tenho um serviço aonde faço um select em uma tabela do schema public, depois para cada item retornado tenho que ir ate o schema do cliente e fazer um select em outra tabela e atualizar algumas informações, bom então meu problema está em como identificar a troca do tenant, veja o meu persistence.xml

```
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource" value="jdbc/GestaoRural" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.multiTenancy" value="SCHEMA" />
        <property name="hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver" value="com.hermes.multitenant.MultiTenantSchemaResolver" />
        <property name="hibernate.multi_tenant_connection_provider" value="com.hermes.multitenant.MultiTenantProvider" />
    </properties>
```

Aqui eu tenho a classe responsável por identificar o tenant, atual pego essa informação do que foi setado manualmente ou do usuário logado, caso não exista ira retornar null e com isso retorno o schema public.

```
public class MultiTenantSchemaResolver implements CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver {

/**
 * Schema padrão.
 */
private  static final String DEFAULT_SCHEMA = "public";

@Override
public String resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier() {

    String tenant = TenancyContext.getCurrentTenant();
    if (tenant != null) {
        return tenant;
    }

    return DEFAULT_SCHEMA;
}

@Override
public boolean validateExistingCurrentSessions() {
    return true;
}
```

O que acontence é que quando faço o select na tabela do schema public ele chama o metodo e retorna corretamento o schema public, o problema é que quando ele vai executar a segunda consulta o método responsável pela identificação do schema não é mais chamado,acho que estou esquecendo de algo mas não sei o que pode ser, alguem tem alguma dica para me dar ?

MultiTenantProvider

```
public class MultiTenantProvider extends DataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(MultiTenantProvider.class.getName());

    @Override
    public Connection getAnyConnection() throws SQLException {
        return selectAnyDataSource().getConnection();
    }

    @Override
    public void releaseAnyConnection(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        connection.close();
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection(String tenantIdentifier) throws SQLException {

        final Connection connection = selectAnyDataSource().getConnection();
        try {
            connection.createStatement().execute("SET SCHEMA " + toSchema(tenantIdentifier));
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Não foi possível alterar a conexão JDBC para esquema especificado ["
                + tenantIdentifier + "]");
            throw new HibernateException(e);
        }

        return connection;
    }

    @Override
    public void releaseConnection(String tenantIdentifier, Connection connection) throws SQLException {

        try {
            connection.createStatement().execute("SET SCHEMA 'public'");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Não foi possível alterar a conexão JDBC para esquema especificado [public]");
        }
        connection.close();
    }

    /**
     * Converter um domínio para uma expressão de um schema do banco de dados.
     * 
     * @param domain tenant domain
     * @return dominio formatado
     */
    private String toSchema(String domain) {

        final int bufferSize = 4;

        int size = domain.length() + bufferSize;

        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(size);
        buffer.append("'");
        buffer.append(domain);
        buffer.append("'");
        return buffer.toString();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

O `MultiTenantSchemaResolver` é apenas o responsável por definir qual schema será usado, o responsável pela "mágica" da troca de schema é o `MultiTenantProvider`. Veja estas sobrecargas dos métodos `getAnyConnection()` e `getConnection(String tenantIdentifier)`:

```
    private ComboPooledDataSource cpds;

    @Override
    public Connection getAnyConnection() throws SQLException {
        return cpds.getConnection();
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection(String tenantIdentifier) throws SQLException {
        Connection connection = cpds.getConnection();
        connection.createStatement().execute("SET SCHEMA '" + tenantIdentifier + "'");
        return connection;
    }
```

Esta é uma versão simplificada da implementação, mas perceba que ao solicitar alguma conexão, o método solicita ao pool, que por sua vez vai fazer o trabalho de solicitar ao hibernate que resolva o tenant e posteriormente chame o `getConnection(String tenant)`, este efetuará a troca do schema na prática.

Se tudo neste ponto estiver ok, pode ser ainda que você esteja fazendo tudo com a mesma conexão, sem requisitar outra ao hibernate, sendo assim, tudo ainda seria executado no mesmo schema.

Comment: isso mesmo @Ricardo, a conexão com o banco é sempre a mesma, pois tenho um banco com vários schemas no  Postgres, andrei depurando o hibernate e ele chama o método responsável por identificar o schema apenas quando cria a session, na segunda chamada a session ja existe e ele tenta identificar o schema novamente, vou posta o fonte do MultiTenantProvider para voce dar uma olhada

Comment: Como você injeta o seu `EntityManager` nos beans? Ele não está ficando aberto?

Comment: acredito que é isso mesmo, ele acaba sendo compartilhado entre os objetos, injeto ele com a seguinte anotação @PersistenceContext, alguma dica de como resolver ?

Comment: A injeção do @PersistenceContext acontece em um bean de que tipo de escopo? @ApplicationScoped? @SessionScoped?

Comment: não há nenhuma anotação de definição de escopo na classe do producer do objeto, no método producer possui as seguintes anotações '@Produces' e '@Dependent'